# Will garbage collector act in the following situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection

Suppose I have the following javascript code:

```
class MyDOMWrapper {
    protected $elem;

    constructor($elem) {
        this.$elem = $elem;
        this.$elem.data('wrapper', this);
    }
}

(() => {
    new MyDOMWrapper(jQuery("#wrapped-elem"));

    /** ... */
})();
```

At this point if I am correct:

- the DOM element is referenced by the **DOM Tree** and the **JQuery Object** (does the JQuery object reference the DOM element, or it is the other way around?)
- the JQuery object is referenced by the **instantiated class**
- the instantiated class is referenced by the **DOM element**

If I am not mistaken, neither of the 3 elements will be garbage collected at this point, because the DOM element is a root element.

What happens, if sometime later in my code, I do the following:

```
/** ... */
jQuery("#wrapped-elem").remove();
```

This will remove the DOM element from the DOM tree, or in other words will remove the only root reference to all of my objects. What I would expect in this situation, that when the next garbage collection cycle runs, all memory will be freed that was allocated to my instantiated class and jQuery objects also. Will this happen, or will garbage collection be prevented because of the inner reference to the jQuery object in the instantiated class?

Comment: The jQuery collection references the DOM element.

Comment: It should be collected, since there's no way to reach the class object. You have a cycle of references, but there's no route to it from the root elements.